# Преобразовать многомерный массив

Tags: php

Пытаюсь получить на PHP(Bitrix) многомерный массив:

```
$List = array(
foreach($arResult["ITEMS"] as $arItem):
    $$arItem["NAME"] = array(
        $Item_2     =   $arItem["DISPLAY_PROPERTIES"]["PROPERTIES_1"]["VALUE"];
        $Item_3     =   $arItem["DISPLAY_PROPERTIES"]["PROPERTIES_2"]["VALUE"];
        $Item_4     =   $arItem["DISPLAY_PROPERTIES"]["PROPERTIES_3"]["VALUE"];
        $Item_5       = $arItems["DISPLAY_PROPERTIES"]["PROPERTIES_4"]"VALUE"];
        $Item_6     =   $arItem["DISPLAY_PROPERTIES"]["PROPERTIES_5"]["VALUE"];
    ),
endforeach;
);
```

Затем мне надо перевести его в JSON, чтобы в конечном итоге получить объект следующего вида:

```
 List = {
   Name_1: {
    Item_1: "properties",
    Item_2:  numder,
    Item_3:  numder,
    Item_4:  numder,
    Item_5: "properties",
   },
  Name_2: {
    Item_1: "properties",
    Item_2:  numder,
    Item_3:  numder,
    Item_4:  numder,
    Item_5: "properties",
   },
  Name_3: {
    Item_1: "properties",
    Item_2:  numder,
    Item_3:  numder,
    Item_4:  numder,
    Item_5: "properties",
   },
   //... 
 }
```

Вопрос:
**как сделать сформировать массив PHP?**

Comment: приведите пример исходных данных.

Comment: Ну это числовые и строчные значения, без булевых

Comment: тогда не знаю чем вам помочь. скажу разве что, очевидно, конструкции `$Item2 = ....;` следует заменить на `'item2' => ... , ` _(запятая в конце)_. и прочие опусы к валидному синтаксису привести

Comment: А есть метод в php по типу как в js .push() ?

Comment: Разобрался! Я пытался весь массив передать с ( ),а надо было переменную.  array_push($List, $$arItem);